# Pre isntalled Ubuntu for Dell Vostro 3580

Tags: dell

I bought Dell Vostro 3580 with pre-installed Ubuntu 18.04. After some time my hard drive crashes and I installed new hard drive but I can not find original Ubuntu .iso for Dell Vostro 3580 laptop. On Dell site when I enter my service tag number it find my laptop but I can't download original iso. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you obtain the ISO from [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/in/en/inbsd1/drivers/osiso/linux)?

Comment: I tried it but it says that there is no OS when I enter my s/n.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct Service Tag... I just searched on ebay to see if I could spy a service tag for a Dell Vostro 3580, found one (F2FLBV2), plugged it into the Recovery Image page, and was shown the recovery images and process. Alternatively, have you tried Dell support, you should be able to Chat/Phone them, advise your situation, and they will support based on the service tag you give them.

Answer (score 0):

**Go to**:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/

**Download**:
ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso
SHA256SUMS

**Validate**:

```
$ cd [path to iso & SUMS files] 
$ sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2>&1 | grep OK
```

Comment: This is not Ubuntu for Dell, this is standard Ubuntu installation but thank you on your answer